# How to get a result from substracting date

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys i want to query out the current date subtract previous date and return the changes of the length (current length - previous length) using SQL. See the sample of the changes as in the table below current minus previous length

I couldn't think of query how to do it
SELECT date, length FROM length_data

```
date                 length          changes
-------------------  --------------  ------------
2000-08-29 10:30:00          147.98  147.98
2000-08-30 00:00:00          147.98  0
2000-09-02 10:30:00          156.51  8.53
2000-09-04 00:00:00          156.51  ....
2000-09-04 04:30:00          156.51  ....
2000-09-04 06:30:00          156.51  ....
2000-09-05 21:00:00          156.51
2000-09-06 03:00:00          156.51
2000-09-07 09:30:00          204.06
2000-09-07 10:30:00          204.06
2000-09-08 00:00:00          339.09
2000-09-08 12:30:00          395.78
2000-09-09 09:30:00          477.77
2000-09-10 02:30:00          737.77
```

Comment: It is very easy. Dependent on RDBMS `LAG/LEAD` or self join to previous row.

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle ...)?

Comment: @KenD the RDBMS is MySQL

Comment: I don't understand the "length" data

Comment: @JeanDoux the length data is in meters so when the current date minus previous date i want to get the changes of the length where current length - previous length see the changes column as example of the result i want

Comment: Does there happen to be an autoincrement field on this table?  That would make the self-join needed to do this easier

Comment: @MikeBrant not auto-increment the depth is manually entered the date can be manually fill in and adjusted as well

Comment: @MikeBrant Even with `AUTOINCREMENT` you could get gaps like `1,2,4,6`

Answer (score 3):

You could use variable to simulate `LAG` windowed function:

```
SELECT `date`, `length`,
       `length` - @prev AS changes,
       @prev := `length`
FROM length_data, (SELECT @prev := 0) AS a
ORDER BY `date`;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a3217/1/0)**</kbd>

I've assumed that `date` is `PRIMARY KEY/UNIQUE` otherwise it won't be stable.

**EDIT:**

To remove additional column you could use subquery.

```
SELECT `date`, `length`, `changes`
FROM (SELECT `date`, `length`,
        `length` - @prev AS changes,
        @prev := `length`
      FROM length_data,(SELECT @prev := 0) as a
      ORDER BY `date`) AS sub
ORDER BY `date`;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a3217/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════════════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║            date              ║ length  ║ changes ║
╠══════════════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ August, 29 2000 10:30:00     ║ 147.98  ║ 147.98  ║
║ August, 30 2000 00:00:00     ║ 147.98  ║ 0       ║
║ September, 02 2000 10:30:00  ║ 156.51  ║ 8.53    ║
║ September, 04 2000 00:00:00  ║ 156.51  ║ 0       ║
║ September, 04 2000 04:30:00  ║ 156.51  ║ 0       ║
║ September, 04 2000 06:30:00  ║ 156.51  ║ 0       ║
║ September, 05 2000 21:00:00  ║ 156.51  ║ 0       ║
║ September, 06 2000 03:00:00  ║ 156.51  ║ 0       ║
║ September, 07 2000 09:30:00  ║ 204.06  ║ 47.55   ║
║ September, 07 2000 10:30:00  ║ 204.06  ║ 0       ║
║ September, 08 2000 00:00:00  ║ 339.09  ║ 135.03  ║
║ September, 08 2000 12:30:00  ║ 395.78  ║ 56.69   ║
║ September, 09 2000 09:30:00  ║ 477.77  ║ 81.99   ║
║ September, 10 2000 02:30:00  ║ 737.77  ║ 260     ║
╚══════════════════════════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

**EDIT 2:**

Using [Jean Doux's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430565/5070879) to calculate it using only one column:

```
SELECT `date`, length,
    CAST((-IF(@prev IS NULL,0,@prev) + (@prev := length)) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS changes 
FROM length_data,(SELECT @prev := NULL ) AS a
ORDER BY `date`;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a3217/16/0)**</kbd>

or the easiest way is to skip additional column in application layer.

Comment: This perfectly do the trick but how can i remove the extra column @prev := `length` from the result?

Comment: thank you very much that looks like it...i can move forward with one of my task.

Comment: when i apply on real table the query seems to load quite sometimes without return result and it keeps loading am i missing something to make it work at optimum loading speed?

Comment: Do you have index/primary key on `date`?

Comment: the primary key is fact_activity_uid and my real query look like this

SELECT `start_datetime`, `depth_md_msl`, `progress`
FROM (SELECT `start_datetime`, `depth_md_msl`,
        `depth_md_msl` - @prev AS progress,
        @prev := `depth_md_msl`
      FROM fact_activity,(SELECT @prev := 0) AS a
      ORDER BY `start_datetime`) AS sub
ORDER BY `start_datetime`;

Comment: You could add index on `start_datetime`;

Comment: i am not in the position to index the database...but if there is anything can improve on your query would be great its just keep loading but i guess its working...can we limit the output just to test if anything comes out..at least we know its working...how can i limit the result output

Comment: I just tried the first query on my sQLyog run in blazing speed...the result instantly popped out but only that the additional column is not needed...

Comment: Try: `SELECT date, length,
      -IF(@prev IS NULL,0,@prev) + (@prev := length) AS changes 
FROM length_data,(SELECT @prev := NULL) as a
ORDER BY date;`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
date, 
length,
@prevLength - (@prevLength:= length) as changes
FROM 
test, (SELECT @prevLength:= 0) as a
ORDER BY account_id ASC, value ASC
```

Comment: Almost correct. But in current form `@prevLength - (@prevLength:= length) as changes` you will get always zeros.

Comment: Yes you are right, we need to use a subquery, should I delete my answer ?

Comment: And if I do SELECT date, @prevLength - length as changes, (@prevLength := length) as length ... It will be ok, right ? Just not the same columns order ?

Comment: The second answer you propose is exactly as my answer above. The point is to make assigment without additional column.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I am still a beginner with variable in mysql :)